# Ampersand in GET, PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, get

I have a simple form that generates a new photo gallery, sending the title and a description to MySQL and redirecting the user to a page where they can upload photos.

Everything worked fine until the ampersand entered the equation. The information is sent from a jQuery modal dialog to a PHP page which then submits the entry to the database. After Ajax completes successfully, the user is sent to the upload page with a GET URL to tell the page what album it is uploading to --

```
$.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../../includes/forms/add_gallery.php",
    data: $("#addGallery form").serialize(),
    success: function() {
        $("#addGallery").dialog('close');
        window.location.href = 'display_album.php?album=' + title;
    }
});
```

If the title has an ampersand, the Title field on the upload page does not display properly. Is there a way to escape ampersand for GET?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general you'll want to [URL-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding) anything that isn't completely alphanumerical when you pass them as parts of your URLs.

In URL-encoding, `&` is replaced with `%26` (because 0x26 = 38 = the ASCII code of `&`).

To do this in Javascript, you can use the function [`encodeURIComponent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp):

```
$.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../../includes/forms/add_gallery.php",
    data: $("#addGallery form").serialize(),
    success: function() {
        $("#addGallery").dialog('close');
        window.location.href = 'display_album.php?album=' + encodeURIComponent(title);
    }
});
```

Note that [`escape`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) has the disadvantage that `+` is not encoded, and will be decoded serverside as a space, and thus should be avoided ([source](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/)).

If you wish to do this serverside at the PHP level, you'll need to use the function [`urlencode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

Comment: I believe "title" is being appended to the URL in javascript, from user input -- there's no opportunity to use PHP's urlencode() in this context.  Ignacio's got it right -- the encoding needs to be done in javascript, in the OP's case.  In other contexts, urlencode() would be the right function to use, though.

Comment: Thanks! Worked beautifully. This is why we test and test our pages :)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.href = 'display_album.php?album=' + encodeURIComponent(title);
```

The javascript `escape` function will not encode these characters: * @ - _ + . /. So if you have title like "this+that", the plus sign will be interpreted as a space and PHP will receive the variable as "this that".

Using the `encodeURIComponent` will also encode the following characters: , / ? : @ & = + $ #