# Sending ampersand in GET

Tags: javascript, http, url, coldfusion, get

I have a drop box which is populated by information from a database. Some of the items have ampersands in them. When the drop box is changed, there is some ajax done, and this includes sending the info from the drop box in a GET. An ampersand in the name of the item from the drop box messes up the URL for the GET.

For example, here is a sample URL generated by the ajax:

```
http://www.website.com/getReports.cfm?date=05/07/2010&room=Visitors Office&system=Windows & Screens
```

The "Windows & Screens" item messes up the get, so what the receiving page gets is just "Windows " for the `system` variable.

What would be the best way to work around this issue without changing the database, in ColdFusion or Javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ampersand in GET, PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748042/ampersand-in-get-php)

Comment: oh snap! indeed it is. Sorry! I think I might have scrolled past that one, discouraged by the "PHP" in the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your client-side code should be building the URL using the Javascript `encodeURIComponent()` routine. To use it, the code should encode the parameter names and values *before* gluing them together with the "?" and "&" characters in the URL.